# extract all recurring substring between string c#

Tags: c#, .net

Have a `string s = "City, State, Country, City,State,Country"`

and return to `List<string>[0] = ["City, State, Country"] and List<string>[1] = ["City,State,Country"]`

thought about use list, but only return to first matched, it will error out when to search the second matched string. Can someone help me out? Thank!

```
    private static List<string> ExtractFromBody(string body, string start, string end)
    {
        List<string> matched = new List<string>();

        int indexStart = 0;
        int indexEnd = 0;

        bool exit = false;
        while (!exit)
        {
            indexStart = body.IndexOf(start);

            if (indexStart != -1)
            {
                indexEnd = indexStart + body.Substring(indexStart).IndexOf(end);

                matched.Add(body.Substring(indexStart + start.Length, indexEnd - indexStart - start.Length));

                body = body.Substring(indexEnd + end.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                exit = true;
            }
        }

        return matched;
    }
```

Comment: Use the [IndexOf(str, startOffset, count)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_IndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_System_Int32_) so you don't have to manipulate the string it self. Instead of using a `exit` boolean, use `break;`

Comment: Can you show use how you call this method?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen
var res = extract(s, "city","country");

Comment: @Timco what input gives you an error?

Comment: Whenever you're asking for debugging help provide all the information necessary for others to help you effectively. Refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to ensure your (future) question(s) are complete and clear for others to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your task correctly something like this should do the trick:

```
private static List<string> ExtractFromBody(string body, string start, string end)
{
    List<string> matched = new List<string>();

    int indexStart = 0;
    int indexEnd = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        indexStart = body.IndexOf(start, indexEnd);
        if (indexStart < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        
        indexEnd = body.IndexOf(end, indexStart);       
        if(indexEnd < 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        matched.Add(body.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd - indexStart + end.Length));
    }

    return matched;
}

string s = "City, State, Country, City,State,Country";  
var res = ExtractFromBody(s, "City","Country"); 
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("|", res)); // prints "City, State, Country|City,State,Country"
```

In your code you were missing exit condition when `indexEnd` was not found and some `Substring`'s were to greedy based on your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This is one occasion where using a regular expression makes sense. I assume the extract should be case sensitive, if not, the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option can be passed into the `Regex.Matches` method as the third parameter.

```
public List<string> ExtractFromBody(string body, string start, string end) =>
    Regex.Matches(body, $@"{start}.+?{end}")
         .Cast<Match>()
         .Select(m => m.Value)
         .ToList();
```

This finds all `Regex` matches that begin with `start` and end with `end` and then converts to a list of strings.

Use it like so in LINQPad:

```
var s = "City, State, Country, abcd City, State, Country";
var start = "City";
var end = "Country";

ExtractFromBody(s,start,end).Dump();
```

and the output is:

```
List<String> (2 items)
City, State, Country
City, State, Country
```

Comment: it only returns 1 result(list[0])

Comment: @Timco Then you aren't calling it like you said you did. Post your actual source string and call.

Comment: @Timco Not sure what you mean - `Dump` is a LINQPad only method and it works on every type.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static List<string> Extract (string message, string s,string end)
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();

            int indexStart = 0;
            int indexEnd = 0;

            bool exit = false;

            while (!exit)
            {
                indexStart = message.IndexOf(s);
                indexEnd = message.IndexOf(end);
                
                if(indexStart != -1)
                {
                    res.Add(message.Substring(indexStart, indexEnd- indexStart + end.Length));
                    message = message.Substring(indexEnd + end.Length);
                }
                else
                {
                    exit = true;
                }
            }

            return res;

        }
```

change a little bit, but the second result only return to "city,s"